# How I can use ucfirst() on PHP SimpleXML node?

Tags: php, simplexml

I use php and simplexml for parse url. I want take value of simplexml node and change it, first I convert it to string, but ucfirst() doesn't work for that string.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer)
{
    $bodyType = (string) $offer->{"body-type"}; //I convert simplexml to string first  
    echo ucfirst($bodyType); // In this line ucfirst doesn't work
}
```

How to deal with it?

UPDATE: Problem was in Cyrillic letters, since ucfirst works only with Latin.
Working solution is to use this function:

```
    $bodyType = (string) $offer->{"body-type"};
    $encoding='UTF-8';
    $str = mb_ereg_replace('^[\ ]+', '', $bodyType); 
    $str = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $encoding), $encoding). mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str), $encoding);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? `var_dump($bodyType);`

Answer (score 0):

Dear plz share your xml file data also. I have used the following and it is working fine..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <offers>
        <offer>
            <body-type>offer 1</body-type>
        </offer>
        <offer>
            <body-type>offer 2</body-type>
        </offer>
    </offers>
</data>
```

my output is

```
Offer 1
Offer 2

HTML: Offer 1<br />Offer 2<br />
```

by following php code..

```
<?PHP
$url = "test.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer)
{
    $bodyType = (string) $offer->{"body-type"}; //I convert simplexml to string first  
    echo ucfirst($bodyType); // In this line ucfirst doesn't work
    echo '<br />';
}


?>
```

Comment: I add actual url and comment for temporary time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the `test.xml` from [Farrukh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745562/624466), you can actually even omit the typecasting. This works as well for me:

```
<?php
$url = "test.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer) {
    echo ucfirst($offer->{"body-type"}) .'<br>';
}
```

Here's a live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/L4VwPL

---

**UPDATE (after URL was provided by OP)**

You'll most likely have an encoding issue. When I set the UTF-8 charset explicitly, it works as expected (otherwise simplexml returns corrupted strings only).

```
$url = "http://carsguru.net/x/used/exchange/4.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer) {
    echo ucfirst($offer->{"body-type"}) .'<br>';
}
```

When I run the above snippet, I get this output (stripped):

```
фургон
универсал
хэтчбек
хэтчбек
минивэн
минивэн
минивэн
седан
седан
универсал
хэтчбек
универсал
седан
хэтчбек
седан
```

**NOTE** You don't serve a content-type/charset header for the xml! I'd add that.

---

Anyway, you may want to have a look at this: [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) -> `iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $str);`

---

> Actually file encoding is Cyrillic windows-1251, which is probably make sence.

Why? You can, of course, use valid UTF-8! Here is an example node from your XML converted with [this cp1251-to-utf8-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#47499) (might look odd, but renders perfectly!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<auto-catalog>
    <creation-date>2013-02-07 02:00:08 GMT+4</creation-date>
    <host>carsguru.net</host>
    <offers>
        <offer type="commercial">
            <url>http://carsguru.net/used/5131406/view.html</url>
            <date>2013-02-07</date>
            <mark>&#1043;&#1040;&#1047;</mark>
            <model>2705</model>
            <year>2003</year>
            <seller-city>&#1057;&#1072;&#1085;&#1082;&#1090;-&#1055;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1073;&#1091;&#1088;&#1075;</seller-city>
            <seller-phone>8-921-997-74-06</seller-phone>
            <price>150000</price>
            <currency-type>RUR</currency-type>
            <steering-wheel>&#1083;&#1077;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;</steering-wheel>
            <run-metric>&#1082;&#1084;</run-metric>
            <run>194</run>
            <displacement>2300</displacement>
            <stock>&#1074; &#1085;&#1072;&#1083;&#1080;&#1095;&#1080;&#1080;</stock>
            <state>&#1061;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1096;&#1077;&#1077;</state>
            <color>&#1089;&#1080;&#1085;&#1080;&#1081;</color>
            <body-type>&#1092;&#1091;&#1088;&#1075;&#1086;&#1085;</body-type>
            <engine-type>&#1073;&#1077;&#1085;&#1079;&#1080;&#1085;</engine-type>
            <gear-type>&#1079;&#1072;&#1076;&#1085;&#1080;&#1081;</gear-type>
            <transmission>&#1088;&#1091;&#1095;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103;</transmission>
            <horse-power>98</horse-power>
            <image>http://carsguru.net/clf/03/af/9c/8b/used.4r9v39h31facog8cs0w0wk8ws.jpg.medium.jpg</image>
            <image>http://carsguru.net/clf/ae/51/be/3a/used.bxyc3q9mx80sko0wg80880w0k.jpg.medium.jpg</image>
            <image>http://carsguru.net/clf/28/dc/c1/d4/used.8i1b76l1b8o4cwg8gc08oos4s.jpg.medium.jpg</image>
            <image>http://carsguru.net/clf/55/3d/37/10/used.7dmn7puczuo0wo4cs8kko0cco.jpg.medium.jpg</image>
            <image>http://carsguru.net/clf/49/02/15/54/used.7k8lhomw4j4s4040kssk4kgso.jpg.medium.jpg</image>
            <equipment>&#1052;&#1072;&#1075;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1086;&#1083;&#1072;</equipment>
            <equipment>&#1055;&#1086;&#1076;&#1086;&#1075;&#1088;&#1077;&#1074; &#1079;&#1077;&#1088;&#1082;&#1072;&#1083;</equipment>
        </offer>
    </offers>
</auto-catalog>
```

Comment: I add actual url and comment for temporary time.

Comment: yeah, but you can see ucfirst() doesn't work for this xml string, first letter is not capitalized!

Comment: nope, I can't see that. I don't read/speak cyrillian. for me it looks all the same. ;-) but you're right. ucfirst doesn't works only with the latin alphabet. Have you tried the function here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php#70752 ?

Comment: thx for your help, I allready found solution on Russian website!